# How to send comment notification message to website admin and post Author using functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, notifications, comments

My question is "How to send comment notification to website admin and also post Author?"...
In Wordpress default function is "Post author received a comment notification message when user add any comments" but my requirement is totally different. In post - Post Author and website admin only comment (communicate) each other. As per WordPress default notification, Post Auther received the notification but when Auther reply or any comments on the post - Website Admin not received any notification messages.

I am using `functions.php` and my code is,

```
function se_comment_moderation_recipients( $emails, $comment_id ) {

    $emails = array( get_option( 'admin_email' ) );

    return $emails;
}
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 'se_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', 'se_comment_moderation_recipients', 11, 2 );
```

As per my above code, Admin only received but I need If admin reply any comments to post, that particular author received some notification message - If Post author reply or comments any, admin received an alert message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Multiple user comment notification, this below code is almost covered my requirement.

```
add_filter('comment_notification_recipients', 'override_comment_notice_repicient', 10, 2);
    function override_comment_notice_repicient($emails, $comment_id) {  
        $admins = get_users( array(
            'role__in'     => array('administrator'),
        ) );
        foreach ( $admins as $user ) {
            $emails[] =  $user->user_email;
        }
        return ($emails);
    }
```

Above code is from this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/311687/sent-comments-notifications-to-multiple-users)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look as below:

- Put a check in the Anyone Posts a Comment box. This completes the process and actually sends out an email to both the admin and author of the post.
- To clarify, it sends out an email to you, the admin, whenever anyone posts a comment on any of the articles that are on your site. This email is the one that you have punched into your own general settings. Now, if you create an author account you also have a chance to punch in an email for that person. So if this isn’t working for you then check to see that all the emails are correct or that you didn’t punch in your own email for the author account.
- Another strange thing about this setting is that the writer must have an Author account as a user on your site. You can’t make them a Subscriber or Contributor. Neither of these will work, so you need to give your writers an Author account.

Please have a look below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Above image is already implemented. No use, As per above mentioned code, admin only received the email but I want both.

Comment: Post author can also receive the notification but for that, you have to update their user role to 'author'